# I was trying to make calcapp using python kivy but crashes in the beginning

Tags: python, android, kivy, calculator

**THIS IS MY .py FILE**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.button import Button

Window.size = (500,700)
Builder.load_file('calc.kv')

class MyLayout(Widget):
    pass

class Screen1(Screen):
     def clear (self):
         self.ids.calc_input.text = "0"
     def button_press(self, button):
         prior = self.ids.calc_input.text
         if prior == "0":
             self.ids.calc_input.text = ''
             #self.ids.calc_input.text = f'{Button}'
         else:
             self.ids.calc_input.text = f'{prior}{button}'
     def  math_sign(self, sign):
         prior = self.ids.calc_input.text
         self.ids.calc_input.text = f'{prior}{sign}'

     def remove(self):
          prior = self.ids.calc_input.text
          prior = prior [:-1]
          self.ids.calc_input.text = prior

     def dot(self):
         prior = self.ids.calc_input.text 
         num_list = prior.split("+")
         num_list[-1]
         if "+" in prior and "." not in num_list[-1]:
            prior = f'{prior}.'
         self.ids.calc_input.text = prior                  
         if "." in prior:
            pass
         else:
            prior = f'{prior}.'
         self.ids.calc_input.text = prior

     def equals(self):
            prior = self.ids.calc_input.text
            answer = eval(prior)
            self.ids.calc_input.text = str(answer) 


            '''
            if "+" in prior:
             num_list = prior.split("+")
             answer = 0.0
             for number in num_list:
                 answer = answer + float(number)
                 
                 
                 self.ids.calc_input.text = str(answer)
                 
            if "-" in prior:
             num_list = prior.split("-")
             answer = 0.0
             for number in num_list:
                 answer = answer - float(number)
                 
                 
                 self.ids.calc_input.text = str(answer)
                 
            if "x" in prior:
             num_list = prior.split("*")
             answer = 0.0
             for number in num_list:
                 answer = answer * float(number)
                 
                 
                 self.ids.calc_input.text = str(answer)
                 
            if "/" in prior:
             num_list = prior.split("/")
             answer = 0.0
             for number in num_list:
                 answer = answer / float(number)
                 
                 
                 self.ids.calc_input.text = str(answer)
                 
                 #self.ids.text = answer
            '''
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class App(App):
    def build(self):
        return WindowManager()

if __name__ == "__main__":
     App().run()
```

**THIS IS MY .kv FILE**

```
#:kivy 2.0.0
<WindowManager>:
    Screen1


<Screen1>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:"vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height

        TextInput:
            id: calc_input
            text: "0"
            halign: "right"
            font_size : 65
            size_hint: (1, .15)

        GridLayout:
            cols:4
            rows:5

#            Button:
#                size_hint: (.2, .2)
#                font_size: 32
#                text: "%"

            Button:

                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "<<<"
                on_press : root.remove()


            Button:
                id: clear
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "C"
                on_press : root.clear()

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "/"
                on_press : root.math_sign("/")


            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "7"
                on_press : root.button_press(7)

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "8"
                on_press : root.button_press(8)


            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "9"
                on_press : root.button_press(9)


            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "x"
                on_press : root.math_sign("*")


            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "4"
                on_press : root.button_press(4)


            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "5"
                on_press : root.button_press(5)


            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "6"
                on_press : root.button_press(6)


            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "-"
                on_press : root.math_sign("-")


            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "1"
                on_press : root.button_press(1)


            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "2"
                on_press : root.button_press(2)


            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "3"
                on_press : root.button_press(3)


            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "+"
                on_press : root.math_sign("+")

#            Button:
 #               size_hint: (.2, .2)
  #              font_size: 32
   #             text: "+/-"

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "0"
                on_press : root.button_press(0)


            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "."
                on_press : root.dot()

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2, .2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "="
                on_press :root.equals()
```

I din't get any error in vs code and even while making apk using google collab but when i tried to install it on andriod it first displayed starting but then suddenly crashed and same happened with bluestacks please let me know if you want to know any thing extra.

Comment: Titles should be titles, not your full story... [ask]

Comment: ok i understand but can you please answer

Comment: If your app works in you IDE and the buildozer creation works. If it only crashs with the .apk on a phone, then use `buildozer android deploy run logcat`. And you should try without `Window.size = (500,700)`, android doesn't like this (windows doesn't care).

Comment: hey can you please suggest my how can i convert to apk i have used google collab this time